# Unterschied zwischen "bereisen" und "reisen nach"

Tags: difference, usage

> (a) Ich bereise Deutschland.
>
> (b) Ich reise nach Deutschland.

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Sätzen? Ich glaube, dass sie die gleiche Bedeutung haben, aber (a) ist vielleicht etwas formeller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"bereisen" ist assoziiert mit mehrfachen, gewohnheitsmäßigen Reisen oder mit Herumreisen innerhalb eines fremden Landes. Es gehört einem formaleren Register an und ist wesentlich seltener. Das sind die Hauptunterschiede.

Answer (score 2):

Wie schon Kilian  gesagt hat, *bereisen* ist das Herumfahren in einem Land, in dem man eventuell schon ist.

*Nachdem ich in Berlin angekommen war, bereiste ich in den nächsten Monaten Deutschland*.

Dagegen bedeutet

*Ich reise nach Deutschland*,

daß man aus einem anderen Land nach Deutschland reist.